# Can we switch to iframe inside an iframe if we first switch to defaultContent()?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, iframe, automation

I'm trying to switch to a frame(2) inside a frame(1) but before doing so, I'm switching to defaultContent(). This is causing my webdriver to not identify the frame(2) and an exception is being thrown. When I remove driver.switchTo.defaultContent(), I'm able to find the frame(2). Can anyone explain why this happens?

```java
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver,entityTypesIframe,WaitUtils.QUICK_WAIT);
driver.switchTo().frame(entityTypesIframe);
```

When I try above code, a TimeOutException is thrown but when I try below code:

```java
WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver,entityTypesIframe,WaitUtils.QUICK_WAIT);
driver.switchTo().frame(entityTypesIframe);
```

I'm successfully able to switch to the frame.
Can anyone explain reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call driver.switchTo().defaultContent(), you essentially reset the WebDriver's focus to the top-level browsing context. Consequently, any attempts to locate elements within frame(2) will fail because the driver is no longer "inside" frame(1) and cannot directly access its contents. It is important to note that the purpose of the defaultContent() method in Selenium WebDriver is to shift the focus back to the default content or the top-level browsing context. Thats is why You need to first switch to frame 1 and then frame 2 to access the elements under frame 2